# Pulling coordinates from Google Sheets. issues with int float cutting everything off. How can I pass as real number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread, gmplot

This prints my latitude and longitude from two columns in Google Sheets:

```
x1 = [item for item in wks.col_values(3) if item]
for item in x1[1:]:
    print(item)

x2 = [item for item in wks.col_values(4) if item]
for item in x2[1:]:
    print(item)

latitude_list = int(x1[1])
longitude_list = int(x2[1])


gmap3 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(31.203993, -71.67483, 9)

gmap3.heatmap(latitude_list, longitude_list)
```

Result:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '31.203993'
```

This is after I tried applying int to int(x1[1])... I tried adding float like this:

```
int(float(x1[1]))
```

but then my coordinates get cut off to the first two numbers... so it's only -71 or 31. How can I pass this list from Google sheets to gmplot?

edit: this is how I'm retrieving data from Google Sheets:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('x.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("x").worksheet("x")

x1 = [item1 for item1 in wks.col_values(3) if item1]
for item1 in x1[1:]:
    print(item1)
    print(Decimal(item1))
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your sheet? How are you retrieving the values in your Google Sheets?

Comment: added retrieval method to edit

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with gmplot but try passing `decimal` or `float` values.

`int` values can not have a fragment as `int` can only represent whole numbers.

the parameters either need to be [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/decimal.html) or [float](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_numbers.htm)

Comment: float wouldn't work. tried decimal: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1) . :headache:

Comment: Got the decimal part to work but now im facing this: TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable
>>>

Comment: That error usually points to a value being passed in should be a list or array, but you are sending in a single value. In this case I would think a method needs a list of decimal values and not a single value.

Comment: I was intrigued by gmplot so I went to the github repository and looked at the code. https://github.com/gmplot/gmplot/blob/0dee8d76df0a2fbf74cfb431486c93634ab78cf6/gmplot/gmplot.py#L661 it looks like it expects a list of tuples.

Comment: list of tuples... okay. I'll start researching how to turn my Google Sheet string list into a list of tuples. Thank you!